# Library for HTML tag creation for Typescript similar to "scalatags"

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a library which makes it easy to create HTML tags from typescript. I have worked with "scalatags" in scala-js, and was wandering if something similar is available for typescript.

The library in question should facilitate writing code in this manner:

```
var paragraph1 = p("Some text");
var paragraph2 = p("Some other text");
var d = div(paragraph1, paragraph2);
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

Comment: not sure whether there's already a library like this, but it won't take many lines to create your own. O.O

Comment: I know it is reasonably easy to create, but I wanted to know if one is already written before writing my own.

Comment: Since TypeScript is so close to JavaScript you could just use JQuery or React or something else that a JS dev would use

Comment: It's not that easy to create if it's not supposed to suck as bad as the respective javascript libraries that do this do: Obviously this question implies that we're going to have some type safety reflecting the html schema, right?

Comment: As @shorn answered below, JSX would suit your needs .. if you are comfortable with mixing JS with html. A sample syntax would be `var paragraph1 = <p>Some text</p>` and `var d = <div>{paragraph1}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Reader beware: I am very new to the Typescript ecosystem, I stumbled across this this question as I was looking for the same thing.

It looks to me like [`JSX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#JSX) is an equivalent library.  I'm not sure if you can use JSX effectively by itself, it's part of the [`React`](https://facebook.github.io/react/) UI library.

But if you look at the React section of the the [Typescript tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) - you'll see JSX (the `.tsx` files) being used in the same way as you would use Scalatags: to render HTML in a type-safe way.

But, at the same time, JSX is very different to Scalatags.  Scalatags is a DSL implemented in Scala which you then use via Scala-js.  JSX is a different language, a "JavaScript extension syntax" - and you get your type-safety via Typescript in the same way as with any other Javascript library.

When following along with the Typescript React tutorial myself, I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I get full intellisense support (completion, find usages, etc.)   The typescript compiler (and IDEA) will both complain when you make errors (typos in names of HTML elements, type problems, etc.)

**EDIT**: the "Non React JSX" section of the [Typescript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/jsx/tsx.html) seems to imply it is possible to use JSX without React.